How disable settings on core/image (Gutenberg) block
How disable settings  on core/image (Gutenberg) block


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Try this
//functions.php

    function disable_all_block_settings($metadata)
    {
        if ($metadata['name'] === 'core/image') {
            $metadata['supports'] = [];
            $metadata['styles'] = [];
        }

        return $metadata;
    }

    add_filter('block_type_metadata', 'disable_all_block_settings');


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
